# What is the most efficient way to take out a tank?

Tags: battlefield-v

I know armor is weaker at the back and that you can target things like the tracks.
But in terms of weapons and gadgets, what is the best way to take out a tank?

I have noticed that 2 stick of dynamite or 2 rockets from the assault class are not enough to take out a tank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the quickest way you can destroy a tank (provided you are assault, with panzerfaust, at granade and sticky dynamite is:

- Get in a favorable position (Behind the tank is best and does the more damage)
- Try to land as many sticky dynamites as you can on the tank, or the nearest possible
- Change Weapon to Panzerfaust, and try to hit the tank in/near the spot you put the sticky dynamite
- Charges will detonate, their explosive damage will add up on Panzerfaust's, providing a burst of damage in a short amount of time. This should destroy all lighter tanks in a single execution from any side. If not, fire the second panzerfaust or add an AT granade to the burst.

Other fast ways of destroying tanks that come to my mind:

- If you are not Assault Soldier, the quickest way to destroy Tanks
  while on foot are AT mines, since they provide the most single hit
  damage. You can also land them (sneaky) near the tank and shoot them
  to trigger the damage, with no need to wait for the tank to step on
  the mines.
- If you can choose a veichle, the quickest way to destroy a tank with one is by bombing it with bombers. Even with no unlocks, provided you land the bombs on target you can take out any tank with a single bombing run.
- If you like armored veichles more, tank destroyers are the most damaging ground veichle to other tanks. Unlocks = even better famages.
- If on foot and with no explosives, the quickest solution is by
  finding a placed cannon and land 3-4 hits on the target.

Bonus info:

- Hand Granades can damage Tanks, but doing a little to almost any
  damage (you'll get a *"Veichle Hit"* Marker with +1/+5 points)
- Boys Rifle can damage tanks, the best spot to hit them is in the rear
  of the turret (5-8 dmg per hit)
- Tanks are immune to fire, so don't waste Incendiary granades
- Also Tromboncino rifle's granade can do a little damage to tanks, but it's very hard to kill them.
- A not-so-effective, but a lot fun way to kill tanks is to place Adhesive Charges and/or AT Mines on one of the destroyable bridges present in some maps, wait for a veichele to pass on it and detonate. It will result most likely in the veichle falling down and often getting destroyed: in addition of the explosions damage, fall damage will add up too! And also, if it lands on its roof (upside down) it will slowly take damage and get destroyed. no matter what the unlucky driver will try!

As others said, destroying tanks is a matter of teamplay. The best possible way you can do it, is to combine some of these instructions with the help of a friend and tanks will have no-hope.

All of my calculations have been made by taking as "damage" the indicator the game provides when you hit a Veichle. I thought the more damage you do, the more points it's gonna give to you, so I used the *"Veichle Hit"* points as my damage value.

Comment: I am not sure why this was downvoted.  There is not really a better way to deal with tanks single-handedly, since this is a team game.  It's literally by design that one person can't just 1 shot a tank.

Comment: This is now a much better answer than it was. Nice job.